# How to prelaod webpages in android and save them to objects that can be given to viewholder to display the webpages in a cardview?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-cardview, android-viewholder

I am trying to make an android app which lets user search a query using SearchView and then displays the results of various websites(not more than 5) like google, youtube, quora etc. in form of cardviews.
How can I do that? please tell me any other way to do it if my approach is wrong.
help much appreciated. I am new to android development.

Comment: Your question is too general. What did you try already? How are you planning to get the data from websites?

Comment: CardView can't show HTML. You need to use something like WebVIew. What is the problem for you to do what you want exactly?

Comment: i have worked with list views , and there i needed to create a sample xml file passed to adapter to customise the layout of a single list item.

Comment: cant i create a custom xml file containing a text view and a webview and then pass it to card adapter?